# Error keeps appearing “syntax error near unexpected tokefi”

Tags: shell, data-recovery, delete

I am creating a script to restore files back to their original location after being deleted and I keep having this error pop up. Why and how to fix the issue?

```
 #!/bin/bash
 if [[ ! $1 ]]; then
 echo -e "Usage:\n\n\t$0 'file name'"
 exit 1
 fi

 f=$(ls 2>/dev/null -l /proc/*/fd/* | fgrep "$1 (deleted" | awk '{print $9}')

  if [[ $f ]]; then
  echo "fd $f file found..."
  read -p "Do you want to recover this file? [Yes/No] " confirmation
   [[ $confirmation =~ ^[YyJj] ]] || { echo "Canceled"; exit }
  cp -v "$f" "$1"
  fi
```

Comment: side note: you should read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: and here's a helpful site: shellcheck.net

Comment: btw, the error in your title appears truncated; it wouldn't hurt to edit the body and show an invocation of your script followed by the exact error message

Comment: I can’t not use shellscript. At the moment. I was trying to edit the body but my laptop is reacting crazy. Thanks for the information. I’m resetting my laptop now to fix the script.

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from the following line:

```
[[ $confirmation =~ ^[YyJj] ]] || { echo "Canceled"; exit }
```

If you add in a semicolon after the exit to indicate the end of the block, it should at least avoid the error that you were recieving:

```
[[ $confirmation =~ ^[YyJj] ]] || { echo "Canceled"; exit; }
```

That said, I am not a big fan of this type of notation, and I personally do not think it's necessary for a case like the one OP had posted. It's not that much harder to write out the full `if/then/fi` statement to avoid these type of syntax issues, plus writing it out would make the script easier to read, share, or debug in the future.

Comment: wow just a semi colon..... thank you so much I miss all the small details. I believe my code is still incorrect because it’s still not restore my deleted files so I’ll be going back to work :(